# Identifying a desert landform

Tags: geography, geomorphology, desert

I saw [this landform on Google Earth](https://www.google.com/maps/@30.378725,9.050503,7822m/data=!3m1!1e3) on the border of Algeria/Tunisia/Libya and wondered what it is called (so that I can read up on it and find out how it forms - I am not a geologist):

[image]

[Here is a 3D view](https://www.google.com/maps/@30.4018266,8.7950013,3316a,20y,82.69h,82.08t/data=!3m1!1e3): (Press Ctrl + drag left mouse button to rotate)

[image]

Does anyone know what kind of landform this is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Erg_Oriental

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Star dunes, caused by the prevailing winds coming from multiple directions.

Take a look at these different [dune types](https://www.nps.gov/grsa/learn/nature/dune-types.htm).